Is the Ronin Institute still active?
I am wondering if anyone knows whether the Ronin Institute is still active? The website seems to have been down for the past week (since I started checking), with a message posted just saying it is 'down for maintenance'.
(If this question is not suitable for Academia SE, I will be happy to delete it. However, there is no contact e-mail listed on the current RI webpage and I'm not sure where else to ask.)

You might check if the Internet Archive, well, archives it, and see when the last update was?

@JonCuster thanks for your suggestion. I checked the Wayback Machine and it seems the site was taken down for maintenance around the end of July (so it has been down a couple of weeks). There are quite a few snapshots from before that though, so I will try to find out more from those and perhaps find some contact info.

I think this is fine, though we're unlikely to get a good answer. If you get the chance, maybe edit in that Wayback link with the snapshot date.

Multiple weeks of "maintenance" seems a bit odd for a functioning organization. Perhaps they got hit by the Crowdstrike thing in July and just haven't recovered yet.

@user176372 I will look into it and see if I can find out what's going on with them. If I find something out, I may post my own answer, to clarify the situation.

Answering as a Ronin scholar (albeit not very active with them recently).
There was a sudden decision by the board to close the institute in the spring of this year. From the sound of it, there were many logistics/financial issues that had accumulated and which the new board was overwhelmed by. Not very clear on all the specifics, but essentially it closed, though there were some initiatives by some members to continue it in some way or form (or maybe join other similar groups), but not clear if there's been any outcome with those.

Thanks very much for your answer and it's a shame to hear about these issues. I would still be very interested to hear whether there is much chance of these things being resolved in the future.

It did not seem that way when the discussion was ongoing around 9 months ago. The way the message was delivered was very abrupt and final, and essentially all of the independent scholars had no idea what had happened. No one on the old board came forward to give guidance either, at least not publicly.
Again, just very strange and sudden. We were also asked to switch away from our Ronin e-mails. There's always some chance that someone manages to revive it, though, so who knows.

I'm posting this as a 'temporary answer' to my own question and will edit/update if the situation changes.
The following message is visible on the Ronin Institute community page in the July 12 snapshot:

How to join?
We are temporarily pausing our membership application process. We grew so quickly over the past few years that a pause is necessary until we are able to provide new members and prospective members the attention they deserve. We will likely resume reviewing membership applications soon, so please check back.

I don't know if this is related to the website being taken down for maintenance; however, based on this, it seems more likely that they are struggling under 'weight of demand' than that they may have closed down. So, that seems encouraging in a way, but also a little disappointing, as I'm about 6 months away from completing my PhD and I am interested in potentially joining the RI as an independent researcher.
I will check back in and keep an eye on the situation over the next few weeks.

That's a fairly optimistic interpretation. Honestly, if they stopped taking in applications and at the same time also took their website offline for multiple weeks, I would not count on them ever coming back. I don't think these are signs for this organisation being "too successful".

@xLeitix it is possible and I agree it does look concerning. If an organization like this had closed down though, I would hope they would post a message to that effect, to clarify the situation for current and prospective members.

I would say they probably have not closed down yet, but it's not looking good.

Hello, @Time4Tea. I am really interested in your intention to join Ronin. I have the same one. I have created a chat room. I am wondering if you can be so kind to share your perspective with me in the chat room, please. Here is the link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154626/discussion-about-the-answer-to-the-question-is-the-ronin-institute-still-active

@IvanNepomnyashchikh I have joined your chat and will share my thoughts. I'd also be very interested to hear from anyone else who is interested in Ronin and/or can provide any information on what their status is.

would be curious what other routes one could go to publish indepent research without an afillition to an institution. arXiv requires someone to be part of an inistitution or to have others approve you. Which was possible via Ronin, if that path is blocked are there other ways, that have credibility?

I have been a Ronin Scholar since 2020 (disclaimer: the opinion stated here is my own) I can confirm that that organisationals matters have not been okay for some time, mostly due to poor management. A lot  happened in the last couple of years and while on the one hand, RI was successful, very successful, on the other hand things happened that were not quite clear (mostly related to management and funding). Many Scholars who do not identify nor were consulted, are trying  first to figure out what is going on, what are the rights and obligations of the respective stakeholders, and if possible to rescue the holding entity (the incorporated not for profit that manages the institute) A few dozens scholars are determined to continue operating if necessary by setting up a new entity.

Stack Exchange frowns on answers that are soliciting personal contacts and as such this answer is attracting spam flags.

Thanks for your answer and it's good to hear from someone who is a current Ronin Scholar. One thing I am curious about though: in what way has the Ronin Institute been successful in the past couple of years? Do you mean in terms of interest from prospective new members?

I have created the following chat room:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155306/ronin-institute-discussion . It might be better to discuss that and possibly share contact info there, rather than here in the main Q&A.

For those who are downvoting: in my opinion it is highly relevant to the question, to hear the perspective from someone who is a current Ronin Scholar. Yes, they posted a link to a shared Google doc (it seems the answerer may be new to Academia SE); however, it would be a great shame to torpedo this potentially valuable answer from a new user, simply because of a technicality that can be (already has been) easily fixed.

@Time4Tea It's not just the Google doc link. The wording of the answer ("became a threat to traditional academia", "was infiltrated", ...) also calls into question the objectivity of the answer. Stack Exchange is not the place to put out calls for action or to discuss internal institute politics.

@xLeitix I see your point. In that case, I will propose the answer be edited, to remove the potentially speculative/accusatory statement. This answer contains valuable insight from an active member of the RI and it needs to be salvaged.
